# Intellij IDEA, GWT-Bootstrap, autocomplete

Tags: java, gwt, intellij-idea, gwt-bootstrap

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
         xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
         xmlns:b="urn:import:com.github.gwtbootstrap.client.ui">
<ui:style>
    .center {
        margin: auto;
    }
</ui:style>
<g:HTMLPanel height="100%" width="100%">
    <b:TabPanel tabPosition="left" ui:field="tabPanel">
        <b:Tab icon="PHONE_SIGN" heading="Все телефоны" active="true">
            <b:Heading size="3">Прейскурант цен</b:Heading>
            <b:Label>
                Тут будет оборажаться таблица с ценами телефонов и количеством оставшихся телефонов
            </b:Label>
            <b:CellTable ui:field="ctPhonePrices" width="100%" condensed="true" striped="true" bordered="true"/>
        </b:Tab>

        <b:Tab icon="USER_MD" heading="Информация о пользователе">
            <g:Label>Тут будет отображаться имя пользователя, его пароль его корзина и совершенные ранее покупки.
                Имя и пароль можно будет менять
            </g:Label>
        </b:Tab>
    </b:TabPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

I'm writing GWT application using GWT-Bootstrap. 
This is example one of many ui.xml, which I use in my program.
When I try to add some GWT-Bootstrap widget and write `<b:` autocomplete in Intellij IDEA does not prorose any variants, but when I write `<g:`, IDEA displays all GWT widgets.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved when i click File -> Invalidate Cashes/Restart... -> Invalidate and Resrtart

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the dependency specified in the pom.xml (or gradle/other build file)?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.gwtbootstrap</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

From the [Maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gwtbootstrap/gwt-bootstrap).

I added the dependency to my project and IntelliJ is suggesting as expected:

[image: IntelliJ Import ui.xml]

Comment: Yes, I have this dependency, but with version 2.2.1.0, in my pom.xml. Also i tried to add gwt-bootstrap-2.2.1.0.jar to External files, but autocomplete syill not working.

Comment: Even reinstall of Intellij IDEA did not help.